# Construct JSON objects from multiple pipelines

Tags: json, powershell

I've been breaking my head over this for a while now. I run two pipelines to produce two arrays of tuples. Each tuple contains a `(filename, property)`.

```
# create pipeline of (file, property1) tuples
$prop1 = Get-ChildItem *.prop1 -PipelineVariable fi |
           Get-Content -Tail 150 |
           Select-String -Pattern "  Pattern1 (\d+)" | 
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
           ForEach-Object { [System.Tuple]::Create($fi.Name, $_.Groups[1].Value) }

# create pipeline of (file, property2) tuples
$prop2 = Get-ChildItem *.prop2 -PipelineVariable fi | 
           Get-Content -Tail 5 | 
           Select-String -Pattern "  Pattern2 (\d+)" | % { $_.Matches } |
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } | 
           ForEach-Object { [System.Tuple]::Create($fi.Name, $_.Groups[1].Value) }

$result = ????
ConvertTo-Json $result
```

Now I would like to combine these tuple pipelines on `filename` to produce JSON output like:

```
[
  {
     'file':'filename1',
     'prop1':'value1',
     'prop2':'value2',
  },
  {
     'file':'filename2',
     'prop1':'value3',
     'prop2':'value3',
  }
]
```

How can I combine these pipelines to produce the desired output? Or am I making this more complicated than necessary?

Comment: And you are sure that there's always the exact same number of tuples in `$prop1` and `$prop2`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding the property values to the filename with a `Tuple`, use a Hashtable where the filename is the key:

```
$FileProps = @{}
Get-ChildItem *.prop1 -PipelineVariable fi |
           Get-Content -Tail 150 |
           Select-String -Pattern "  Pattern1 (\d+)" | 
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
           ForEach-Object { $FileProps[$fi.BaseName] = @{ 'filename' = $fi.BaseName; 'prop1' = $_.Groups[1].Value }}

Get-ChildItem *.prop2 -PipelineVariable fi | 
           Get-Content -Tail 5 | 
           Select-String -Pattern "  Pattern2 (\d+)" | % { $_.Matches } |
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } | 
           ForEach-Object { $FileProps[$fi.BaseName]['prop2'] = $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Now create a bunch of custom objects based on the hashtable entries and convert them to json:

```
$Json = $FileProps.Keys |ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psobject -Property $FileProps[$_]
} |ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I could not get the nested hashtable right.